# Compound (complex) feature in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

I was playing around with OpenLayers a bit and was wondering if there was a way to create custom "Features". What I want to accomplish is a feature that has multiple parts or if there is a way to "bind" multiple features together.

What I want to accomplish with this is that I want to show various amounts of data on a map at a certain position and I'd like to wrap it in a border (kinda like a callout).

As far as I know there are several ways to accomplish this but each with its own downfall:

- Generate a single image server side that has content + border. The problem with this approach is that I waste a lot of calculation time on the server and deliver essentially the same picture partially for every point on the map.
- Use multiple features. The problem here is that when I modify the shown data on mouseover I only can react to the mouse over of one feature and not to all of them.

So is there a way to create custom features in OpenLayers? How would I go about doing so? Or is there even a simpler way with a compound/complex feature that I just haven't discovered yet?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it not possible to add multiple attributes to a feature and achieve what you want ?

     var feature2 = new openLayerObj.Feature.Vector(point, {
            customAttr: customAttr,
            radius: 20
        });

http://jsfiddle.net/alexcpn/FDzJv/